# enum function and subtract old value with new value on swift

Tags: swift, enums, subtraction

I am trying to calculate how much the semitones of musical notes changed with an enumerator function in Swift but I don't know how to apply it. Here's what I've done:

```
enum TonalityChange: String{
    case C = "1/2"
    case Csharp = "1"
    case D = "1(1/2)"
    case Dsharp = "2"
    case E = "2(1/2)"
    case F = "3"
    case Fsharp = "3(1/2)"
    case G = "4"
    case Gsharp = "4(1/2)"
    case A = "5"
    case Asharp = "5(1/2)"
    case B = "6"
}
```

Then I declare a var for the enumeration:

```
var OldTonality : B
var NewTonality : C

var Difference : //This will do the subtraction result
```

Then I have to subtract both values to get a natural number that will let me know the change like:

```
6 - (1/2) = 5(1/2)
```

Finally, I want to make an alert message to show like:

```
"Great! Tonality changed by \(Difference) tones!"

or "Great! Tonality changed by (1/2) tones!"
```

But I've been all day thinking about how to do this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Make TonalityChange a Float instead of a string:

```
enum TonalityChange: Float {
    case C = 0.5
    case Csharp = 1
    case D = 1.5
    case Dsharp = 2
    case E = 2.5
    case F = 3
    case Fsharp = 3.5
    case G = 4
    case Gsharp = 4.5
    case A = 5
    case Asharp = 5.5
    case B = 6
}
```

Now you can do diffs.

```
let diff = TonalityChange.B.rawValue - TonalityChange.C.rawValue
```

Comment: I would also add a function to the enum that returns the specially formatted string for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
enum TonalityChange: Float {
    case C = 0.5
    case Csharp = 1.0
    case D = 1.5
    case Dsharp = 2.0
    case E = 2.5
    case F = 3.0
    case Fsharp = 3.5
    case G = 4.0
    case Gsharp = 4.5
    case A = 5.0
    case Asharp = 5.5
    case B = 6.0

    var formatedString : String {
        switch self {
            case .C : return "1/2"
            case .Csharp : return "1"
            case .D :  return "1(1/2)"
            case .Dsharp : return "2"
            case .E : return "2(1/2)"
            case .F : return "3"
            case .Fsharp : return "3(1/2)"
            case .G : return "4"
            case .Gsharp : return "4(1/2)"
            case .A : return "5"
            case .Asharp : return "5(1/2)"
            case .B : return "6"
        }
    }
}

let difference = TonalityChange.B.rawValue - TonalityChange.C.rawValue
let newValue = TonalityChange(rawValue :difference)
print(newValue!.formatedString)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try it!

Comment: hmm i get two errors: The first one says : 'Value of type '(EditProject) -> () -> (EditProject)' has no member 'difference'.' The second is :

Comment: last three lines are only for demonstration . I  added these to demonstrate functionality . i compiled this code and it's working fine . @CVar open this link http://tpcg.io/nnrNEb

Comment: great! now I get it! I was totally missing the bang(!) from newValue